# How to use SeekBar for mediaplayer on xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to use SeekBar for time of a track on mediaplayer. And That show lenght of time and time currently as below picture
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question. Show us some code you already did.

Comment: Media are playing and seek bar will running, which base on time of media has played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/ it might help you but you will need to convert it from native code.

Also you could try to use the sample for the [seekbar](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/seekbar/) with the [play video sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/video/play_video/) and hook up the listeners for `SeekBar.IOnSeekBarChangeListener`somethign like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987317/syncing-video-view-with-seekbar-with-onstoptrackingtouch)